# SPARC using scanf() to read characters

Tags: c, input, sparc

Alrighty here's my problem. I am trying to take a character from a users input using scanf() and print it back out to them in SPARC Assembly. This code is simpler than what I am actually trying to do but it is the thing I am hung up on. It works fine with strings but for some reason not with characters.

SPARC code:

```
  .section ".data"

prompt:   .asciz   "\nPlease enter your name: "

format:   .asciz   "%c" 

format2:  .asciz   "Your name is:%c\n"  



/* Program starts */ 


.align 4 

.section ".text" 

.global fun

 fun: 

save %sp, -96, %sp      ! save the stack


set prompt, %o0         ! point o0 to the prompt 

call printf             ! call printf to print the prompt 

nop 


set format, %o0         ! point o0 to the input format string

set ch, %o1             ! point o1 at the input variable 

call scanf          ! get the input into this variable 

nop 



set format2, %o0        ! point o0 to the output format

set ch, %o1             ! point o1 to the string to be displayed

call printf             ! print the string pointed by o1

nop

ret                 ! return 

restore             ! get out
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 char ch;



int main()

{

fun();

 }
```

Comment: If you make the code in C and compare the `scanf` call between scanning for a string and scanning for a character, you will see that there are two differences: The format, and how you pass the destination argument. Have you modified the assembler code to accommodate for that difference in argument passing?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I have changed the format to %c as you can see and I am using the address of the global variable ch defined in the C code. Are these the only differences? I thought they were.